# Cryptolens throws error: No active subscription found

Tags: python-3.x, license-key

The thing is I watched several videos and read the guide on the site https://app.cryptolens.io/ but it doesn't work :(

I would be glad for any support. You can advise another system to create and manage license keys on Python.

```
from licensing.models import *
from licensing.methods import Key, Helpers

RSAPubKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>sDHS5RJSXyqiciGkBlpvKsodTefBQBVG+3RZCmtnZ+j0AGYpx19Q1aYpfRiN1CG9NcQhP6VLm1SLM4Wf63qAHiUh/k8PjYroNoxQsqbYw/0lPc+TbsyAWJvDWeIFsPwLpv3v0uOvj1EtRXja+ddBaZAp1dqAVIMVNRLl3J44vCe0PCuCh30jZlSWf5Gzf0pxAhQjaGYKl4nRfpjxGA/9YGkt8Qj5/+nT/yJk0HW2oRCneRW78XWh6e2EX6IGDbVSausypNOwW9gb1bGPvsJG3nFZyJrvumLPD782fHFKEzCqMT0RkVDXkQntxzcj/3uzHqId3us7KNQKvGZqr4nMQQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>"
auth = "WyI1MDY1NDc1IiwiQjlTMVZ5ZENzRnVTekt5UGF6SXhSMWJDaE92Qm0ybk9QdVN6aE5YdCJd"

result = Key.activate(token=auth,\
                   rsa_pub_key=RSAPubKey,\
                   product_id=12740, \
                   key="KXVIM-FZEKV-LPVEX-JIYTD",\
                   machine_code=Helpers.GetMachineCode())

if result[0] == None or not Helpers.IsOnRightMachine(result[0]):
    print("The license does not work: {0}".format(result[1]))
else:
    # everything went fine if we are here!
    print("The license is valid!")
    license_key = result[0]
    print("Feature 1: " + str(license_key.f1))
    print("License expires: " + str(license_key.expires))
```

There are key, token and other info:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/11BIbyHu3Q22nMGuDF4XdItkmdds1w6pwZuryzUseIVs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was updating billing information, that is I needed to enter card data on the page https://app.cryptolens.io/billing.

P. S.

When I created my account the issue was not.